# Why can't I configure a static ip on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am trying to add a static ip address on raspberry-pi and can't get it working...

ifconfig on pi

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.68.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.68.255
inet6 fe80::1e8e:49a0:5bf:ad41  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether b8:27:eb:c4:41:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 210  bytes 49138 (47.9 KiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 189  bytes 28376 (27.7 KiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

gateway

```
192.168.xx.x
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 62.179.104.xxx
nameserver 213.46.228.xxx
```

dhcpcd.conf settings:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.68.68/20
static routers=192.168.xx.x
static domain_name_servers=62.179.104.xxx 213.46.228.xxx
```

I have also tried `static ip_address=192.168.68.68/24`

reboot pi and `hostname -I` it still gives me the origin ip: `192.168.68.104`

What am I doing wrong here? or Is there another way to set a static ip on raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure the dhcpcd service is enabled and running:

```
sudo service dhcpcd status
```

If that is not the case:

```
sudo service dhcpcd start
sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd
```

Now you can edit the dhcpcd config (like you already did)

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

If you have a network cable use: eth0 and on wifi: wlan (not wlan0)

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.4/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Configure this like you need.

After this reboot.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I had tried that but didn't work.. so afterall I reinstalled the OS then I could set the static ip